Determine whether $\{\int_0^1 f^2(t)dt = 0\}$ is a subspace of $C([0,1],\mathbb{C})$, complex-valued case
I am currently self-studying through a text on linear algebra, and one of the problems asks to determine whether the set $\mathcal{U} = \{f \in C([0, 1],\mathbb{C}) \colon \int_0^1 f^2(t)dt = 0\}$ is a subspace of $C([0, 1],\mathbb{C})$. As a convention, the text considers $C([0, 1],\mathbb{C})$ the vector space of continuous complex-valued functions over the interval $[0, 1]$ (with $\mathbb{C}$ as the vector space's field of scalars).
This question here is undoubtedly related; however, that question only considers the case of when $f$ is a real-valued function. The "real analysis" results used in answering this question (such as the integral of a continuous, nonnegative function being zero implies the function is identically zero) seem to break down when we consider complex-valued functions.
I approached the problem by seeking $f, g$ such that $f \in \mathcal{U}$, $g \in \mathcal{U}$, but $f + g \notin \mathcal{U}$. I settled on $f(z) = \sqrt{2z - 1}$ and $g(z) = \sqrt{\cos(\pi z)}$. I believe that $f \in \mathcal{U}$ and $g \in \mathcal{U}$ as these are both continuous complex-valued functions, and the integral of their squares from 0 to 1 is zero.
Now, consider $f + g$, where $f, g$ are as stated above. Then,
$$
\int_0^1 (f + g)^2(t) dt = \int_0^1 f^2(t) + g^2(t) + 2f(t)g(t) dt = 2\int_0^1 f(t)g(t) dt = 2\int_0^1 \sqrt{(2t - 1)\cos(\pi t)} dt,
$$
and numerically evaluating this interval via WolframAlpha yields an answer of approximately $0.563i$. The natural conclusion is that the set $\mathcal{U}$ is not a subspace of $C([0, 1],\mathbb{C})$.
I have a few questions. Firstly, is my above reasoning accurate? If so, is a simpler counterexample possible? I do not know how to analytically evaluate the final integral. Using other square roots of polynomials such as $h(z) = \sqrt{3z^2 - 2z}$ rather than my current function $g$ seem to be almost as cumbersome to evaluate.
Otherwise, please point out any flaws in my example.

@Mittens I understand that this is true for real-valued functions. However, in any proof of this I've seen for real-valued functions, we assume there exists some $c \in [0, 1]$ such that (WLOG) $f(c) > 0$, and construct a nonzero compact interval around $c$ for which the output of $f$ is positive to obtain a contradiction. I'm not sure how such an argument could be extended to functions whose output may be complex, where we cannot exploit the ordered-ness of $\mathbb{R}$.
If you know where to find a proof of this, please point me there! Thanks.

I did not notice that you are assuming functions to be complex valued.  I made an edit to your posting to stress that...

If one allows complex valued continuous functions, then $\mathcal{U}$ is not a linear space. Consider $f(x)=e^{2i\pi x}$. Then $\int_{[0,1]}f^2=\int_{[0,1]}e^{4i\pi x},dx=0$ Similarly, $\int_{[0,1]}(\overline{f})^2=0$. However
$f(x)+\overline{f}(x)=2\cos(2\pi x)$ does not belong to $\mathcal{U}$.

$\mathcal{U}$ is not a linear subspace of $\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{C})$. Here is a simple counter exaple that shows that $\mathcal{U}$ is not closed under addition. Consider $f(x)=e^{2i\pi x}$. Then $\int_{[0,1]}f^2=\int_{[0,1]}e^{4i\pi x}\,dx=0$ Similarly, $\int_{[0,1]}(\overline{f})^2=0$. However
$f(x)+\overline{f}(x)=2\cos(2\pi x)$ does not belong to $\mathcal{U}$.
